# Hyperloglog for Tinkerpop, .count() approximation

Tags: tinkerpop, hyperloglog

Is there a solution similar to Hyperloglog for graph databases like Tinkerpop. .count() step takes forever on large dataset, however approximation would be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

For TinkerPop-enabled graph systems, the solution for "counting" is typically handled by Gremlin OLAP (typically with [Spark](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sparkgraphcomputer)). Some graphs may optimize for things like counts - as a very simple example TinkerGraph detects something like `g.V().count()` and bypasses the process of iterating all vertices to count them up. Also, some graphs may also provide their own APIs for providing "counts" so it is worth learning a bit about the graph you are using to determine if such capabilities exist.